# fullCalendar: I'm having trouble rendering events with years prior to 100 (years 0000 - 0099) (using ISO8601 format)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, momentjs, iso8601

I'm building a Calendar that shows different events via [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io). the events range is from years 0001 - 6000.

the fullcalendar expect to get the dates in ISO8601. and i'm passing to him the dates in this format.

when i i'm rendering events from years 0100-6000 evrythings works fine and the events are displaying perfectly.

but when i want to display years prior to 100 (0001-0099), the events do not display in fullcalendar.

here are 4 event Date exsampls (this string is send to fullcalendar as the events date in ISO8601 format):

2016-01-23 (works fine)

0253-01-23 (works fine)

0099-01-23 (problem: the events are not displayed at the calendar)

0009-01-23 (problem: the events are not displayed at the calendar)

Anybody know what the problem \ solution?

thanks!

Comment: Which version of fullcalendar  are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Removed previous answer as OP found the cause was unrelated to `fullCalendar`, but to their use of `new Date()`.

Comment: thank you very much for your comment and your great effort. However, I tried switching to moment.min.js version 2.10.3 and this did not fix my problem. I will continue investigating it and update.

Comment: It could be useful to provide a very small fiddle/snippet that demonstrates the problem, but only if you can make it really small -- not with hundreds of lines to build events, and such.

Comment: This is working fine in latest version with moment https://jsfiddle.net/m53jbwx0/3/

Comment: But OP is sending the year with zero padding. `moment('0099-01-23')` should give the correct year. Probably the issue is unrelated to `YYYY` support.

Comment: thanks sabithpocker. i was able to fix it. the problem was that i used new Date () in JS to define the defultdate. thanks again to you and trincot!

Comment: Wow, so it was completely unrelated to `fullCalendar` and `momentjs`. Good to hear you found it.